# C++ exception preventing cout print

Tags: c++, exception, cout

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f()
{
    throw 1;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cout << "Output: " << f() << endl;
    }
    catch (int x)
    {
        cout << x;
    }
}
```

Why isn't `"Output: "` printed? Shouldn't the `operator<<(cout, "Output: ")` be called before `operator<<(cout, f())`? If the line is atomic, how is the printing reversed then?

Comment: Why would you think that `cout` uses the distributive property like this?  Wouldn't it make more sense that all the arguments are evaluated first?

Comment: I neglected the fact that f() could be evaluated before the `operator<<(cout, "Output: ")`. I thought that the arguments would be evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the order of argument evaluation for the << operator is not defined in the c++ standard. It looks like your compiler evaluates all arguments first, before actually printing.

Comment: That's true for any two expressions in a single statement, not just operator `<<`, right?  Which is also why we shouldn't write `int i = 0; std::cout << ++i << "\n" << i++ << "\n";`, `int i = 0; f(i++, i++);` or the proverbial `int i; i = i++ + ++i;`.

Comment: @5gon12eder not exactly, it's a matter of *sequence points*. Which you can look up for more information. But it's often the case indeed.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, single statements that don't introduce sequence points (hope this is the correct wording), I should have added.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to think about the actual operator function calls being assembled as `operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, "Output:"), f()), endl)`: then you can see that `operator<<(cout, "Output:")` and `f()` are just two function arguments to another invocation of `operator<<`: there's no requirement about which function argument is evaluated first.